# Replacing cross-reference text with custom text in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, cross-reference

I have the following text:

> ... uses *broadcasts* to send messages ...

The `broadcasts` bit needs to be a cross-reference to the heading titled `broadcastService`.

If I add the reference using `References \ Cross-Reference`, the reference works but the text is changed to `broadcastService`.

How can I make sure the original text (*broadcasts*) is kept?

The code of the reference is `{ REF _Ref436984305 \h }` *(after doing Alt-F9)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with cross reference.

Do it with hyperlink instead:

- right click on the word
- select `Hyperlink`
- on the left select "Place in this document"
- Select the heading you want to refer to
- click `OK`

### Update

Cross reference and hyperlink look different, cross-reference is stored as a field, while hyperlink isn't.

Playing around a bit they behave similarly when document is edited and location of referred heading is changing they both follow it well.
The only difference I found is that if you move heading by cut and paste to other location, cross-reference is still correct, while hyperlink still refers to the original position, but I don't think this would happen often.

Comment: That works well, thanks! Is there a downside to using `hyperlink` instead of `cross-reference`? Perhaps the latter has more functionality that the former lacks?

Comment: Losing the link on cut / paste is an issue, but not being able to use fluid text that makes sense in the sentence, is a far bigger one. The former issue does occur often while your document is at draft stage, in my experience, but it's survivable. Thanks for the update!